# How do you change the color of an icon in an R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny app that uses a couple icons from the Font Awesome library (built-in) in the UI:

`icon("bolt")`

`icon("compass")`

How do I change the color of each icon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the beginning of the UI, insert `tags$style(".fa-bolt {color:#E87722}")` to change the color of the bolt icon. Similarly, add `tags$style(".fa-compass {color:#E87722}")` to change the color of the compass icon. This will apply the coloring to all bolt icons and compass icons in the app.

Comment: cool, helped for another icon related thing i'm working on. A follow up, what if two buttons use the same icon, but you only want to change the color of icon "x" of button 1, and not button 2?

Comment: a found a way to do that already. i.e.: 
  tags$style("#ClickonMe .fa-ban {color:#E87722}"),

Comment: Use the "class" argument in the `icon()` function. For example, if you have two "bolt" icons, use the following for your second icon: `icon("bolt",class="bolt2")`. Then add a new style like such: `tags$style(.bolt2 {color:#E87722})`.

Comment: it won't work if you already have a fa-.... piece in the icon code because it's a class argument. Unless you know a way to add 2 classes to one item

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I removed the "fa-" class from the second icon listed in the question description to avoid confusion.

Comment: Only that will now block you from using size factors like "fa-2x" because they are a class. So doing this will need a solution to use 2 classes, or my  solution with the button name # rather than class

Answer (score 8):

You can just use HTML tags instead of using `icon()`

```
tags$i(
    class = "fa fa-check-square", 
    style = "color: rgb(0,166,90)"
)
```

e.g.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$p("icon:"),
    tags$hr(),
    tags$i(
        class = "fa fa-check-square", 
        style = "color: rgb(0,166,90)"
    ),
    icon("check-square")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
icon("bolt", style = "color: rgb(255,255,0)")
icon("bolt", style = "color: #ffff00")
```

According to `?icon` regarding the ellipsis `...`:

> Arguments passed to the <i>⁠ tag of htmltools::tags